# making one button trigger another in html

Tags: python, html, django-forms, django-templates

I have a button that lets user download a file, and I have a form that needs to `POST`ed whenever the user clicks on download button.

```
<a class="down" href="{{x.image.url}}" download="none">
     <button>get</button>
</a>
<form action="/image_info/" method="POST" id='image_form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name='info_button' type="hidden" value="{{x.id}}>
    <button class="imginfo" type="submit">info</button>
</form>
```

So, in this I want the `image_form` to be submitted and the image to be downloaded when the `down` button is pressed.Basically the `imginfo` submit button should be pressed when the download button is pressed.

Comment: On pressing the download button are you calling any function?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? will need more info on what else are you using?  with jQuery you can bind a click event to the download button and then form.submit();;

Comment: @iamentafaz no I'm not calling any function. the Download button just downloads the image in the url

Comment: @Amyth yes I can use jQuery for that could you tell me how can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an onclick event to the download button like this

```
    <a class="down" href="{{x.image.url}}" download="none"><button onclick="myfunc()">get</button></a>
```

now define a js function `myfunc()` to submit form whenever the download button is clicked

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
          function myfunc()
          {
            document.getElementById("dform").submit();
          }
        </script>
```